# C++ Program does not return the correct factorial value

Tags: c++, return, factorial

I'm fairly new to C++ and was attempting to write a program that uses a Do-While loop to calculate the sum from 1 to n where n is an input parameter, and uses a factorial function in a for loop to calculate the factorial of n. However, when the program is compiled I get results such as:

The total from 1 to n (where n is five in this example) is 001ED2A8 or some other weird combination of numbers and letters. The same thing happens for my factorial result. I would appreciate any and all help I can get. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int total(int);
int factorial(int);

void main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Please enter a positive number:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "The total from 1 to " << n << "is " << total << endl;
    cout << "The factorial of " << n << " is: " << factorial << endl;
}

int total (int n)
{
    int i, total;

    total = 0;
    i = 1;
    do
    {
        total = total + i;
        i = i + 1;
    } while (total <= n);
    return total;
}

int factorial (int n)
{
    int product = 1;

    for (;n>0; n--)
    {
        product = n * product;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  The debugger will enable you to execute each statement individually and *watch* values of variables.  Using a debugger is a **lot faster** than posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to use a debugger for you.

Comment: `main`'s return should be `int` not `void`. I'd suggest reading up on how to call functions. All you're doing is displaying function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
long factorial (int n)
{
if (n >= 1)
    return n*factorial(n-1);
else
    return 1;
}
```

or use for loop as follows

```
for(i=1,f=1;i<=n;i++)
{
   {f=f*i;}
}
```

Comment: This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
cout << "The total from 1 to " << n << "is " << total << endl;
```

it is equivalent to

```
int (*function_ptr)(int) = total;
cout << "The total from 1 to " << n << "is " << function_ptr << endl;
```

You are passing a *function pointer*  to `operator<<`, not the *value returned by a call to the function*.

In that context, the function pointer gets converted to a boolean value, `true`. Hence, that call is equivalent to:

```
cout << "The total from 1 to " << n << "is " << true << endl;
```

The same thing happens with the next line.

To print the value returned by those functions, you have to make the function calls. Use:

```
cout << "The total from 1 to " << n << "is " << total(n) << endl;
cout << "The total from 1 to " << n << "is " << factorial(n) << endl;
```

Also, you should change the return value of `main` to `int`:

```
int main()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, that was the error in the program. I made that function call and now it is working properly. Thank you for your help and clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
To use a for loop as follows: 
int f=1, i=1;
for(i=1,f=1;i<=n;i++)
{
   {f=f*i;}
}
```

Comment: This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.